# python list comprehension tuple unpacking

Tags: python

If I have data that looks like this:

```
data2 = [('group_l1s', 1.2209625244140625), ('group_l2s', 2.5210751851399777), ('group_l2n', 6.081540250778204)]
```

Is it possible to use list comprehension to unpack the tuple data into a list with just the first strings elements only. For example the final output to look like this:

```
data2 = ['group_l1s','group_l2s','group_l2n']
```

Sorry still learning I know there is a lot of these questions on SO.

If I try `sorted_list = [group for group in data2]` this just returns:

```
[('group_l1s', 1.2209625244140625),
 ('group_l2s', 2.5210751851399777),
 ('group_l2n', 6.081540250778204)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> data2 = [('group_l1s', 1.2209625244140625), ('group_l2s', 2.5210751851399777), ('group_l2n', 6.081540250778204)]
>>> [data[0] for data in data2]
['group_l1s', 'group_l2s', 'group_l2n']
```

Comment: Thank you ill hit the green check when I can